# phpmyadmin privileges only working on some databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I use PHPMyAdmin to edit or delete a record I am getting an error saying "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/sql.php on this server." But this only happens in some databases. I am the only user according to PHPMyAdmin and through the command prompt on my Linux box.

First off I've changed the PHPMyAdmin access folder because my access logs were showing others trying to get in. Logs don't show any successful attempts.

It was working until today...Now it throws the error. I can still add and drop tables completely, just not edit a record, in two of the five databases. Also I've checked into the user privileges and there doesn't seem to be an issue there.

Anyone have an idea?

EDIT: I have narrowed this down to a conflict between mod_security and PHPMyAdmin, now off to Google to find the solution, 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same issues when you log as the MySQL root user (I presume you control the box completely)?

Comment: Yeah doesn't matter if I login as root or as the user I created for myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was I opened modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_47_common_exceptions.conf and added the following to the bottom:

SecRuleEngine Off

And viola it fixed all the issues